# Find No. of newest entries in MySQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I use this query to get the newest 1 entry:

```
SELECT * FROM Data ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

I am using `node-mysql` in `nodeJS`, I would like to use the

```
rows[0].Data
```

So I can get the 4 newest entries in separate variables, how can  I achieve this?

I am aware that I can up the DESC LIMIT to 4, to limit the results, but am still failing trying to get more than 1 result.

Answer (score 2):

for the 4 recent  the sql is

```
SELECT * FROM Data ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 4
```

for obtain the data should be

```
rows[0].Data 
rows[1].Data
rows[2].Data
rows[3].Data
```